# Agent Training in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have written and submitted an app via DialogFlow for Google Home which is now live.  If I make use of the training facility in DialogFlow (https://dialogflow.com/docs/training-analytics/training) and match un-matched user questions to existing intents, do I need to resubmit my app to google for the training to take effect?  Unfortunately the documentation is not clear on this point.

Comment: I think you don't need to resubmit as it will update by itself once you save the changes in Dialog flow. (this worked for me with facebook messenger and skype bot)

Comment: Thank Umer - I think those implementations work in a different way to the Google Assistant as you submit a packaged up app to google. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I contacted DialogFlow re the question and they confirmed that that app does need to be resubmitted to google if you use their training function as this alters the language model.